# Error in downloading mnist data unknown url type: HTTPS

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, https, mnist

when I try to load the mnist dataset using the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

it gives me an error message saying:

```
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz: None -- unknown url type: https
```

I know that the issue is with the line `(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()` but I couldn't find anything online on how to solve it. I am using windows 10 and I Jupyter notebooks and Anaconda.

Comment: It works for me so it probably has something to do with network/OS settings.

Comment: No problems for me neither

Comment: @Kent Shikama do you know which settings precisely?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Do other datasets work? What about a plain url fetch?

Answer (score 1):

In the `mnist.py` file, change the

```
origin_folder = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/'
```

to

```
origin_folder = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. find folder where your python installed, example: `Python 3.11`
2. open folder and then run file: `Install Certificates.command`
3. Be happy :)